# Cannot load .so file in R

Tags: r, error-handling, load, .so

I have been trying to load a shared object file ".so" into my R however it continuously comes up with an error (note, my Path is written as `[PATH]`).

```
Error in dyn.load("McCOIL_categorical_code.so") : 
  unable to load shared object '[PATH]/McCOIL_categorical_code.so':
  dlopen([PATH]/McCOIL_categorical_code.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
  Referenced from: [PATH]/McCOIL_categorical_code.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Could anyone please advise? Thank you so much in advance!!

Comment: Does the file /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/lib/libR.dylib exist?

Comment: The `libR.dylib` file is from R version 3.2.x.  Unless you're using that ancient version of R, you won't be able to load that .so.